# Visual Studio has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

It seems the breakpoint is due to heap corruption.
Here's a snapshot of two frames from the call stack:

First:

```
void QString::free(Data *d) 
{
#ifdef QT3_SUPPORT
    if (d->asciiCache) {
        QMutexLocker locker(asciiCacheMutex());
        Q_ASSERT(asciiCache);
        asciiCache->remove(d);
    }
#endif
    qFree(d);//Breakpoint here, d = 0x08c9efd4 
}
```

Second:

```
void qFree(void *ptr)
{
    ::free(ptr); //Breakpoint here, ptr = 0x00000000
}
```

What makes me confused is the pointer is `0x08c9efd4` before it is passed to `qFree` and suddenly becomes `NULL` when it is passed to `qFree`.

What may cause the sudden change of the pointer ?

Comment: May be caused by double-freeing the string. Show more frames of call stack and describe how do you use this string.

Comment: A second possibility is mixing debug and release in the same application or using any dll that was built with a different compiler than the one you are using.

Comment: On top of that you may have heap corruption caused by some other deallocation (double freeing some other object in the past).

Comment: In your call stack, back up to a point that is your own code (if possible). Show us that. Are you by any chance explicitly `delete`ing any Qt widgets? You know about Qt's parent-child ownership?